# Error when navigating to user auth page

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

The facebook C# SDK generates an url that looks like this:

`http://m.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?response_type=token&display=popup&scope=user_about_me&client_id={MY APP ID}&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&confirm=1`

(obviously I've set the APP id in the real code).

Problem is that the lougout page presents a very generic error message "An error occurred. Please try again later.". If I cut the oauth part out and navigate to that, oauth works fine. But it seems like the NEXT parameter isn't really panning out.

Any pointers? This is with the latest 5.0.9 (BETA) build of the SDK.

Comment: could u paste the code on how you are generating the logout url.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  What I did was remove the braces (the '{' and '}') from the App Id to get it to work.  Hope that helps